# Parsing Errno22 with xml Element Tree

Tags: python, elementtree

I am trying to develop a simple web scraper of sorts, and keep having issues with the parsing code for the XML file used.

Whenever I run it it gives me Errno22, even though the path is valid. Could anyone assist?

```
try:
    xmlTree = ET.parse('C:\TestWork\RWPlus\test.xml')
    root = xmlTree.getroot()

    returnValue = root[tariffPOS][childPOS].text
    return returnValue
except Exception as error:
    errorMessage = "A " + str(
        error) + " error occurred when trying to read the XML file."
    ErrorReport(errorMessage)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are supposed to escape backslashes in Python strings

```
ET.parse('C:\\TestWork\\RWPlus\\test.xml')
```

or you can use raw strings (note the `r`)

```
ET.parse(r'C:\TestWork\RWPlus\test.xml')
```

Comment: Thank you. So that got me further but now it errors out with
+  error ParseError('not well-formed (invalid token): line 32, column 109') ParseError

Am I mising something else, maybe?

Comment: @Pr0gramDark Yes, your XML is not well-formed. Try opening the XML in Google Chrome. It will show you exactly where the error is (line, column, error message). Open the file in a text editor in parallel, and keep editing out any errors and reloading in Chrome until Chrome shows it correctly. Then Python will be able to read it as well.